# What is the common factor in this case?

Tags: factoring

I have a sum as given below:

$ -51y^7 - 34x^7 \over 17 $

What is the factored from of this question.

Note : I know the factor of 51 and 34 is 17 but is the factor of -51 and -34   17 or -17????

Comment: you should define what do you mean by "factor". In my opinion $17$ and $-17$ are both factors of $\pm 51, \pm 34$.

Comment: by factor i mean common factor.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you can factorize the $-51$ & $-34$ each in two following ways $$-51=(-3)\times (\color{blue}{17})=(3)\times (\color{red}{-17})$$
$$-34=(-2)\times (\color{blue}{17})=(2)\times (\color{red}{-17})$$